# How to keep jquery from descending too far?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a problem with jquery going a bit too far on pattern matching of CSS classes and IDs.

I have some markup that looks like this:

```
  <div id="blah">
    <div class="level2">
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="levelA">
      <div class="level2">
        <input type="text" value="foo"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="bar" />
```

I want for the 3 inputs to say

- Hello
- Foo
- Bar

so I have this line of jquery:

```
$('#blah .level2 input').val('hello');
```

the problem now is that jquery is a bit too liberal in it's pattern matches and matches both the first and second.

How can I prevent this kind of thing from happening?

A live example is at http://jsbin.com/opelo3/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
$('#blah > .level2 input').val('hello');
```

`>` means direct descendant.

Comment: Ah I had seen that character before but being unable to search for it, didn't know what it meant. That does exactly what I need(in my actual code). Thanks!

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html came up after a quick server for "css operators" (I wanted to see what other operators existed).

Comment: @halk that's a good amount of information there. I had no idea there was a `+` operator